# How can I create a generic service that can handle different JSON POJO requests, execute client calls and return their respective responses as well?

Tags: java, json, generics

Currently, we are creating different services to handle different JSON Pojo requests. Each of these services are customized to build the json requests because each request has different parameters as shown in the code.
What I want? 
Avoid code duplication
Create a single service that can handle different json requests, construct a json payload based on the request body, automatically add the parameters based on the request and execute the http client call, how can I do this?

You can see which json object am using through the import I have shown in the code.

```
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class GoogleSearchService {
    public GoogleSearchResponse getGoogleSearchResult(GoogleSearchRequest request) {

    Response response = customHttpclientService.post("googleUrl")
                 .headers("added headers here")
                 .requestBody(MediaType.application_json, buildJsonObject().toString())
                 .execute();
    /*The getGoogleSearchRespons() method will parse the response 
    from the response object.
    */
    return getGoogleSearchResponse(response);

}

private JSONObject buildJsonObject(GoogleSearchRequest request) {

    JSONObject object = new JSONObject():
    object.put("paramOne", request.getParamOne());
    //And so on all params are added like this in each service
}

}
```

Comment: Why not just use a factory pattern to build the JSON you need?

Comment: Oh ok I will look up factory pattern. Lol sorry I have never used it before. New to software development.

Comment: But how will that solve the parameters problem. Each POJO will have different set of requests correct for which I need to map them into a json. How can I do that dynamically?

Comment: If you look at the above buildJsonObject() method, inside that the jsonObject is mapping the parameters as paramOne and fetching the paramOne from the request object and so on. So Instead of hardcoding paramOne, I want the compiler to automaitcally add the parameter name and map the value to it.

Comment: You might think about using something like `gson` to serialize/deserialize. If you do, you can create a custom deserializer and then build out a factory to create the objects you need.